# Wordpress embed video in snippets on Blog home page

Tags: wordpress

I understand how to embed a video into a Wordpress post.  Easy stuff.

Then, on the Blog home page, I see the title of the blog post and a snippet of text (50 chr or so).  Of course, many snippets are present.

Question:  How can I display the actual video inside the snippet?  So that a visitor to my blog home page (www.mysite.com/blog) sees the last 10 blog entries with a video window in each snippet?

That way, a visitor can watch the video directly on the /blog page and not have to drill down each time to watch the video.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theme is most likely using the [`the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) function to show the post previews on your home page, which automatically strips out HTML tags like video embeds.

You can override this behavior and allow HTML to be parsed in your post excerpts using custom template code as described in [the answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt/141136) or with a plugin like [Advanced Excerpt](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/).